# Produce a list of polygons that a line crosses

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fme-form, intersection, overlay, spatial-join

I have a polyline feature class and a polygon feature class. What I want to do is add a field to the lines that lists all polygons that touch the line. This is effectively performing a select-by-location finding the polygons that touch each individual line then add the names of each of these to an attribute. Does anyone know how I can do this in ArcGIS Desktop or FME? My Python is not great but I can give it a go if that's the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create an FME workbench which does what you want with relatively few transformers.  I created a line feature class with two lines which cross several property boundaries.  Here's a screenshot of my workbench with summary annotation (I'm aware it may look small on screen, but you can view the image in a new window and it should appear larger):

[image: FME Workbench]

My polygon feature class was in a different projection, so first, I reprojected the polygon layer to match the line layer.  But after that, these are the steps:

1. Use a SpatialRelator transformer to perform the intersection/touches
   tests.  Lines are BASE and the polygons are the CANDIDATES.
2. Use a ListExpressionPopulator to create a list from attributes. 
   This attribute would be your ID field in your polygon layer.  In my
   case it was called 'LotPlan'.
3. Use a ListDuplicateRemover to remove duplicate values from the list.  You may not need
   this one but my polygon layer contains duplicate ID's if a property is split by a road.
4. Use a ListConcatenator to create an attribute which contains a list of all the ID's.  I 
   used a semicolon to separate the ID's.
5. Use an AttributeRemover to delete all the lists now.  Again, you may not need this, but       if you're doing additional processing, it can free up some memory.
6. Write your output file.  I didn't actually do this in my Workbench.  I just used an  inspector.  However, you could write to a new file and join this back to your original.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a bit late to the party, but for future reference: a simple `Spatial Join` in ArcMap will do the trick. Define a *Merge rule* to the concatenate the IDs of multiple features into a single field.

- Target features: Polyline layer
- Join features: Polygon layer
- Join type: One-to-One
- Field map: right-click a text ID field of your Polygon layer and set *Merge rule* to *Join* to concatenate multiple Polygon IDs into a single field.  You can define a join delimiter like `';'`, `','` in the field properties.

Check [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/executing-tools/using-the-field-mapping-control.htm) for details on Merge rules.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend writing a python script for this task (which you could incorporate into a [script tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001500000006000000)).  The general script flow would go something like this:

1. [Add text field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000047000000) to polyline layer (preferred use a polyline geodatabase feature class)
2. [Make feature layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) of the polyline layer
3. Use [update cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) on feature layer and pull out each ID value that you will use in the select by attribute function
4. Use feature layer ID value in the [select layer by attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000) function to select polyline feature
5. Use [select layer by location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000) function with selected feature layer and polygon layer to select the intersecting polygon(s)
6. Use [feature class to feature class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) function to export out selected polygon features to a temp layer
7. Use [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/) on temp polygon layer to generate a list of attributes based on the "Name" or "ID" field
8. Convert list to a string and write the string variable to the current record you are on within the update cursor (step 3 above)

Step 4-8 will continue for each loop iteration of the update cursor.  This should give you give you a field in your polyline layer with the associated polygon IDs or polygon Names that intersect.

Comment: Thanks, trying this at the moment. So does the update curser create a loop that will repeat for each unique comination of attributes selected in there? So to make it run for each line I select my unique identifier? like this: with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("TEMP_LINES", "LINE_ID") as cursor:
for row in cursor (steps 4-8)

?

Comment: and in step 6 how do I make this a temp layer, rather than create a shapefile or gdb feature class is this is what this seeems to do?

Comment: @whatahitson, Yes, the update cursor will loop through all your polyline features one by one (e.g. for row in cursor:).  The temp layer in step 6 is just a temporary feature class or shapefile, you can use the arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True, statement to allow for overwriting of layers.

Comment: I'm slightly stuck on the last step. How do I write the string I've created to the new field? should I select it in step 3 or was that just the Line ID i was selecting there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000) for this type of analysis.  To elaborate, I have simplified some data:  A polyline shapefile and a polygon shapefile.  After running the Intersect, you can see the results of the attribute table.  The highlighted polyline segment shows that it is intersecting polygon C.  From there, simply query your intersected polyline attribute table to extract any information you need.  Keep in mind you can [summarize](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000055000000) data or [report](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004v00000002000000) data too.

[image]

[image]